# css hover an background-repeat is not working

Tags: html, css

I have completed play popup youtube video. Now i am struggling in hover an image part. I need , when an hover an image, it should show play button with opacity.

So that I tried:

```
.youTubeVideo:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.videoThum:hover{
    background-image:url('playbutton.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
}
```

Now, when an hover, opacity only working, image didn't show. But if i remove no-repeat, it shows play button.

[Live example on the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsps3tec/)

Comment: You missed to add  `background-size` property

Comment: it is working on fiddle .try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/495vbwy2/10/

Comment: @JigneshKhokhariya: For me only working opacity, image didn't show, but in your fiddle working fine.

Comment: had you try my fiddle example? please put your updated css code .so i can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

[Live example with your code.](http://jsfiddle.net/5a1zm7kv/)

```
.videoThum:hover{
    background-image:url('http://www.californiagrinders.com/images/playbutton.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
}
```

Comment: Yes, `div` and `background-image` have different size. But code is correct! Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) for more info about `background-size` property.

Comment: in which div you said?

Comment: The photo in box has `300x300px` and hover image `450x400px` image if you hover these image, it will deforms. The hover image must be the same size or the same rate. Code is correct, images are bad!